# Regular expression operations

Tags: python

I came across this

'[\s]+(.[\w]+)[\s]+([0-9a-fA-F]{8})[\s]+([0-9a-fA-F]{8})[\s]+([0-9]{1,10})[\s]+([0-9a-fA-F]{1,8})'

how to find which patterns has been intended to match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A regular expression (also called regex) is a pattern for processing text, here is the wikipedia page: [Regular_expression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression).

For example, you could search all the mail adresses in a text with a regex like that:
`.+@.+\.[\w]{2,4}`

In python you can use it with the builtin library [re](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/re.html).

Following the previous example, you could do:

```
import re

r = re.search(r".+@.+\.[\w]{2,4}", my_text)
```

This would return a Match object if an email adress is found within your `my_text` string.

If you need to understand what a particular regex do, there are plenty of website that provides cheatsheets or testing tools, here is one: [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)

Comment: Nice, please mark the question as answered if that helped you to solve your issue